# What differences are between capturing by [&captured] and by [&local = captured] in lambdas?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

```
vector<int> vec;

//a
auto foo = [&vec](){
    //do something
};

//b
auto foo = [&v = vec](){
    //do something
};
```

Do I understand it right that only difference between a and b is creation of alias "v" for "vec" in b case or is there more to it?

Comment: There is more info about that [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) but the relevant snippet is *"A capture with an initializer acts as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable declared with type auto, whose declarative region is the body of the lambda expression..."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is basically none. It's just there to allow you to give the captured value a custom name.

Note however that this syntax (called init capture) is required when you want to actually move an object into the closure:

```
std::vector<int> vector;
auto lambda = [vec = std::move(vector)]() { /* the lambda owns the vector now */ });
```

Comment: This does not capture an rvalue reference. It capture a value constructed using an rvalue reference.

Comment: That's technically correct. I clearified the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that's any better. "Capture by reference" is taken to mean `[&vec_ref = vec_orig]`, so people would expect "capture by rvalue reference" to create a lambda capture variable that is itself an rvalue reference, but again, what you actually create is a value. It just happens to use its move constructor by casting the RHS to an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 11):

In this case there is no real difference. However, if you were to capture by value there would be a difference:

```
const std::vector<int> vec; // note const

auto foo = [vec]() mutable {
   // can't change vec here since it is captured with cv-qualifiers
};

auto bar = [v = vec]() mutable {
    // can change v here since it is captured by auto deduction rules
    // (cv-qualifiers dropped)
};
```